# Where can I find the recipe for Uni Rice Bowl?

Tags: bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night

One of Susie's quests appears to be asking for a Uni Rice Bowl. It looks like I had some in the past from another quest, but I guess I ate them all because I don't have any now. So, I need to make one. Where can I find the recipe book item containing this recipe?

I have explored 100% of the map without finding it, and if there are any chests that I couldn't access before, they're not showing up on the map and I don't remember where they might be. And this is the only quest line I haven't finished, so I'm sure that recipe book is not a quest reward I can get.

Comment: Judging from the ingredients, the recipe is likely in the Oriental Sorcery Lab somewhere, but I couldn't say that for sure.

Comment: I haven't really paid much attention to where I got recipe books and what recipes they contain, so I don't actually know if recipe books are generally located in a way that relates to their ingredients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fish recipe is in the Underground Waterway. You will need invert (or high jump) to get it, but the map square will fill in when you're passing through the area before you have that ability. You can see a map of it [here](https://www.steamah.com/bloodstained-ritual-of-the-night-recipes-hairstyles-locations/#_Cooking_Recipes).

[image: Recipe location map]